# Copying and pasting data from multiple website into excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am new to VBA coding. I want some data from [NSE Company tracker websites](http://www.nseindia.com/companytracker/cmtracker.jsp?symbol=%22Name_Of_Scrip%22).
I tried using below code

```
Private Sub IE_Automation()
Dim R As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim ieurl As String
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True 'internet explorer run command
For *R = 2 To 10*
ieurl = "http://www.nseindia.com/companytracker/cmtracker.jsp?symbol=" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(*R*, 1)
IE.navigate ieurl 'internet url
Do
DoEvents
Loop While IE.Busy

IE.ExecWB 17, 2 'IE page selection command
IE.ExecWB 12, 0 'IE page copy command

Range("A2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False 'IE page data paste command in excel

Next R

End Sub
```

Please Use below Scrip code at Place of **R**:
MANAPPURAM,
PDSMFL,
MINDACORP,
CIGNITITEC,
SHEMAROO,
SUPERHOUSE,
SHARDACROP,
SNOWMAN,
SBIN

While I am executing above code, VBA is pasting only data for first Scrip and sometimes it is showing debug error at copy paste code. If I am debugging macro manually(using F8 key) it is correctly executing the procedure.

I wanted to copy and paste the data for all scrip (one by one) into excel.

Please help me to scrap the data from the website into excel.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is executing correctly while in debug mode, the issue may be nothing more than the debug mode allowing more time for the page to actually load completely. I've found that it is best to check for both `.Busy` and the `.readyState` before attempting operations on the page being loaded.

```
Do
  DoEvents
Loop While (IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
```

This can be put into a single code line as,

```
Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE): DoEvents: Loop
```

The `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` constant is equal to 4. These are defined in the VBE's Microsoft Internet Controls reference.

More at [readyState property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534361).